# Fallo en almacenamiento del arreglo funcion promedio

Tags: c, funciones, array

Tengo este codigo para un trabajo universitario pero tengo problemas al momento de calcular el promedio de los datos que se ingresaron al arreglo. Realice impresión del arreglo en la función promedio y arroja valores posiblemente aleatorios y no entiendo por qué. Agradezco si pueden ayudarme a resolver el problema. Gracias

/******************************************************
 *Problema 2: codificar una funcion y dar uso         *
 *Input: Arreglo de 1D tipo int, tamaño del arreglo   *
 *Output: Promedio de datos                           *
 ******************************************************/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

//prototipo

int tamano_arreglo();
int llenar_arreglo(int tam);
float promedio (int *a, int tam);

//main

int main () {

int tam,arreglo = 0;
int *a;
float prom = 0;
tam = tamano_arreglo();
arreglo = llenar_arreglo(tam);
a = &arreglo;
prom = promedio(a,tam);
printf("El promedio de los datos ingresados es: %f \n",prom);


}

//desarrollo prototipos

int tamano_arreglo(){

int tam = 0;
printf("Ingrese el tamano que desea tener el arreglo \n");
scanf("%d",&tam);
return tam;


}

int llenar_arreglo(int tam){

int i = 0;

int a[tam];

for (i=0; i<tam;i++){

    printf("ingrese el valor %d:\n",i+1);

    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
 }
 for (i=0; i<tam;i++){
    printf("Posicion # %d: %d\n",i,a[i]);
 }
 return *a;
 }

 float promedio (int *a, int tam) 
 {
 int i=0;

 float suma, promedio = 0;

 for(i=0; i<tam; i++)
 {
    suma += a[i];
 }

 for (i=0; i<tam;i++)
 {
    printf("Posicion # %d: %d\n",i,a[i]);

}

printf("la suma es %f \n",suma);

promedio = suma / tam;

return promedio;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

El error que tenias era que imprimias dos veces el arreglo, y cuando lo recorrias no ibas guardando la suma, luego solo referenciabas el arreglo(no sumado) por eso hacia operaciones raras

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

//prototipo

int tamano_arreglo();
float llenar_arreglo(int tam);
//main

int main () {

int tam,arreglo = 0;
int *a;
float prom = 0;
tam = tamano_arreglo();
prom = llenar_arreglo(tam);
printf("El promedio de los datos ingresados es: %f \n",prom);


}

//desarrollo prototipos
//asigna el tamaño del arreglo
int tamano_arreglo(){

int tam = 0;
printf("Ingrese el tamano que desea tener el arreglo \n");
scanf("%d",&tam);
return tam;


}
//obtiene el tamaño de la funcion tamaño de arreglo
float llenar_arreglo(int tam){
 float suma, promedio = 0;

int i = 0;
int a[tam];

//pide los valores a promediar

for (i=0; i<tam;i++){

    printf("ingrese el valor %d:\n",i+1);

    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
 }
 //imprime el arreglo y va sumando los datos introducidos
 for (i=0; i<tam;i++){
    printf("Posicion # %d: %d\n",i,a[i]);
        suma += a[i];
 }
//imprime la suma
 printf("la suma es %f \n",suma);
//retorna al promedio, la suma de los datos introducidos / datos intoducidos
promedio = suma / tam;
return promedio;

 }
```